# Bluetooth speaker plays only system sounds

Tags: bluetooth

I am running ZorinOS and using a Bose bluetooth speaker.  After installing blues, blueman, pavucontrol, etc, and reconfiguring /etc/pulse/default.pa to get zorin to recognize my speaker as an audio device, it now somewhat works.

If I open a terminal, completion and error sounds play through the speakers. However, all other sounds play through other output devices.  Is there any fix?

Comment: Start `pavucontrol`, start audio application, check if application uses correct sink (change if necessary). If that was the problem, set Bose as default sink.

Answer (score 0):

Start `pavucontrol`, start audio application, check if application uses correct sink (change if necessary). If that was the problem, set Bose as default sink.